# Null pointer exception while using jsp:usebean

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting a Null pointer exception while using the object created by `<jsp:usebean>`. The object has been properly instantiated, (`<jsp:getproperty>` is running fine ).But when I pass this created object in static method of `Register` class,its throwing a Null Pointer Exception.

NewFile.htm

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form action="NewFile.jsp">
Name<input type="text" name="textbox1"/>
<br>
ID<input type="text" name="textbox2"/>
<br><select name="select1">
<option>India</option>
<option>France</option>
<option>Japan</option>

</select>
<br>
<input type="submit"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

NewFile.jsp

```
<%@ page import="com.psl.Register" %>
<jsp:useBean id="emp" class="com.psl.Employee"/>
<jsp:setProperty property="name" name="emp" param="textbox1"/>
<jsp:setProperty property="country" name="emp" param="select1"/>
<jsp:setProperty property="id" name="emp" param="textbox2"/>
<jsp:getProperty property="country" name="emp"/> 
<%Register.register(emp);%>
```

Register.java

```
package com.psl;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Register {
    public static void register (Employee obj)
    {

        try {
            PreparedStatement stm = DBConnection.establishConnection().prepareStatement("insert into Person values (?,?,?)");
            stm.setString(1,obj.getName() );
            stm.setInt(2, obj.getId());
            stm.setString(3, obj.getCountry());
    stm.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
package com.psl;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Employee {



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + ", country=" + country
                + "]";
    }

    private String name;
    private int id;
    private String country;


    public Employee() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }


}
```

DBConnection.java

```
public class DBConnection {

private static Connection con ;
public static Connection establishConnection()
{try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","root","root");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }   
return con;

}
```

}

Comment: Let's see your `establishConnection` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","root","root");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

An `Exception` is probably being thrown and you are swallowing it, ie. **not handling it**. `con` remains `null`, but you return it.

```
DBConnection.establishConnection()
```

therefore returns `null`.

You try to call

```
prepareStatement("insert into Person values (?,?,?)");
```

on `null`.

---

[Don't use scriptlets.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: Yup I have included the printstacktrace and I could see the exception now.The sql jar file was not placed in web-inf due to which I was getting an exception.

Comment: @Sanjana Always take care in handling the exceptions explicitly. Your handling doesn't have to be intense, but at least logging the exception will go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

The codes looks fine but thr may be two below reason to get `null pointer exception`.
As you are getting the `connection` from method `DBConnection.establishConnection()` so check this is providing proper and valid connection.

The other thing can be `Employee obj`, the `obj` can be `null`,as you are calling it from `.jsp` so check it.

Comment: In this case, `obj` cannot be `null`. OP is passing `emp` from the JSP which is referencing an object created by the `JspServlet`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes i knw dear.Only providing the possible case to throw null pointer exception

Comment: Ok, then that one is not a possible case.